# Can a program/browser detect the usage of vpn to bypass international restrictions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

Can a program or a browser script detect that I am using a VPN to bypass international restrictions if I use the "create new network VPN" on windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you go through a public VPN service the website could feasibly maintain a list of the IP addresses associated with that VPN service.  They can't detect the fact that you're using a VPN specifically.